# Convergence of $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin(n^k)/n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Does $S_k= \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin(n^k)/n$ converge for all $k>0$?

**Motivation**: I recently learned that $S_1$ [converges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test). I think $S_2$ converges by the integral test. Was the question known in general?

Comment: I am not sure you can apply the integral test here for $k=2$. Isn't the function being non-negative a necessary condition?

Comment: @Moron: you might be right. I thought I could use this one: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2305031?cookieSet=1 , but may be I made a mistake.

Comment: @curious I don't think so. Suppose $f(x)=\sin(x^2)/x$, we have $f'(x)=2\cos(x^2)-\sin(x^2)/x^2$. If $\int f'(x)$ converges absolutely, then $\int \cos(x^2)$ converges absolutely, contradiction! I think integral test wouldn't work if the integrand is oscillating near $\infty$.

Comment: If we can bound the finite sum $\sum_{m=1}^{n}\sin(m^k), \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$, then we can use [Dirichlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) test to prove the convergence.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This is a replacement for my previous answer. The sum converges, and this fact needs even more math than I believed before.

Begin by using summation by parts. This gives 
$$\sum_{n=1}^N \left(\sum_{m=1}^N \sin(m^k) \right) \left( \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right) + \frac{1}{N+1} \left(\sum_{m=1}^N \sin(m^k) \right).$$ 
Write $S_n:= \left(\sum_{m=1}^n \sin(m^k) \right)$. So this is
$$\sum_{n=1}^N S_n/(n(n+1)) + S_N/(N+1).$$
The second term goes to zero by Weyl's [polynomial equidistribution theorem](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/03/28/254b-notes-1-equidistribution-of-polynomial-sequences-in-torii/). So your question is equivalent to the question of whether $\sum s_n/(n(n+1))$ converges. We may as well clean this up a little: Since $|S_n| \leq n$, we know that $\sum S_n \left( 1/n(n+1) - 1/n^2 \right)$ converges. So the question is whether
$$\sum \frac{S_n}{n^2}$$
converges.

I will show that $S_n$ is small enough that $\sum S_n/n^2$ converges absolutely.

The way I want to prove this is to use [Weyl's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality). Let $p_i/q_i$ be an infinite sequence of rational numbers such that $|1/(2 \pi) - p_i/q_i| < 1/q_i^2$. Such a sequence exists by a standard lemma. Weyl inequality gives that
$$S_N = O\left(N^{1+\epsilon} (q_i^{-1} + N^{-1} + q_i N^{-k})^{1/2^{k-1}} \right)$$
for any $\epsilon>0$.

---

Thanks to George Lowther for pointing out the next step: According to [Salikhov](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html), for $q$ sufficiently large, we have
$$|\pi - p/q| > 1/q^{7.60631+\epsilon}.$$
Since $x \mapsto 1/(2x)$ is Lipschitz near $\pi$, and since $p/q$ near $\pi$ implies that $p$ and $q$ are nearly proportional, we also have the lower bound $|1/(2 \pi) - p/q|> 1/q^{7.60631+\epsilon}$.

Let $p_i/q_i$ be the convergents of the continued fraction of $1/(2 \pi)$. By a standard result, $|1/(2 \pi) - p_i/q_i| \leq 1/(q_i q_{i+1})$. Thus, $q_{i+1} \leq q_i^{6.60631 + \epsilon}$ for $i$ sufficiently large. Thus, the intervals $[q_i, q_i^{7}]$ contain all sufficiently large integers.

For any large enough $N$, choose $q_i$ such that $N^{k-1} \in [q_i, q_i^7]$. Then Weyl's inequality gives the bound
$$S_N = O \left( N^{1+\epsilon} \left(N^{-(k-1)/7} + N^{-1} + N^{-1} \right)^{1/2^{k-1}}\right)$$

So $$S_N = \begin{cases} O(N^{1-(k-1)/(7\cdot 2^{k-1}) + \epsilon}) &\mbox{ if } \ k\leq 7, \\
O(N^{1-1/(2^{k-1})+\epsilon}) &\mbox{ if } \ k\geq 8, \end{cases}$$
which is enough to make sure the sum converges.
${        }{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I hate to say this, but I am getting worried about whether I can push Weyl's inequality to do what I want. Weyl's inequality says, if $|\chi - p/q| < 1/q^2$, with $GCD(p,q)=1$, then $S_N = O(N^{1+\epsilon} (q^{-1} + N^{-1} + q N^{-d})^{1/2^d})$. What if the convergents to $\chi$ grow so fast that either $1/q$ or $q N^{-d}$ is as large as $1/ \log N$, for any choice of $q$? I was working from my notes from a course which claimed the $O(N^{1-1/2^d+\epsilon})$ bound,  but I no longer follow the proof which was written there. So I have some concerns.

Comment: David, your proof can be fixed up to work perfectly. Just needs one extra ingredient  - pi has finite irrationality measure

Comment: In fact, the mathworld website has a table of bounds for the irrationality measures of some constants, including pi. (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html)

Comment: Sweet! I'll edit this in, feel free to post your own answer if you'd like.

Comment: I'll leave you to complete this so that there's a single complete answer. As $1/2\pi$ will have the same irrationality measure as pi, $\mu=7.6304$ it follows that for all $r>\mu$ and large enough M, you can choose $M^{1/(r-1)}\le q\le M$ in Weyl's inequality. Using $N^{k/r}\le q\le N^{k(1-1/r)}$ seems to give a nice bound and, otherwise, your original answer does not have to be changed so much (which I thought was a very nicely written answer, btw).

Comment: @David: will you consider writing this up somewhere (else)?  I think a lot of people would be interested to see it.

Comment: @Pete: What level of writing up are you thinking of? I'm sure this isn't interesting enough to publish. I am still curious about what we can say about $\sum \sin (\theta n^k)$ for general irrational $\theta$, without any diophantine conditions.

Comment: David - for general irrational theta, I've thought of counterexamples showing can diverge (both the sin and cosine series, for every k>1, all simultaneously for the same theta). Using a similar argument as in my answer to your related MO question,  which I can tidy up a bit ( might go back and edit that answer).

Comment: @David: it might be publishable somewhere, but I respect your high standards of what to try to publish.  Anyway, how about a nice texed up writeup including references?

Comment: Perhaps I am just addled, but it seems to me that $\sum_{n=1}^N \left(\sum_{m=1}^N \sin(m^k) \right) \left( \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right) + \frac{1}{N+1} \left(\sum_{m=1}^N \sin(m^k) \right)=\left(1-\frac{1}{N+1} \right )S_N + \frac{1}{N+1}S_N = S_N$, not $\sum_{n=1}^N S_n/(n(n+1)) + S_N/(N+1)$ as claimed (I "fixed" $s_N$ to $S_N$).

Comment: @robjohn The expression should be $ \sum_{n=1}^N\left(\sum_{m=1}^{\fbox{$n$}}\sin(m^k)\right)\cdots $, which gives the result David announced.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer The bound for $S_N$ depends on $k$. If $k\geq 8$, then the inside paranthesis must be $O(N^{-1})$. Thus, it gives $$S_N=O(N^{1-\frac1{2^{k-1}}+\epsilon})$$ for $k\geq 8$.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer I realized that was actually my edit 5 years ago after carefully following your argument. It seemed to me at that time the term $(k-1)$ should be on the numerator. However, I did not realize at that time that the inner error term need to be more carefully dealt with due to the extra $N^{-1}$ terms.  Now, after reading your solution again, it is possible to optimize more to have a stronger result when $k<8$, and the above comment when $k\geq 8$.