# Convergence of the series $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{ (-1)^n} { \ln(n) +\cos(n)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{ (-1)^n} { \ln(n) +\cos(n)}$$

Comment: This was mentioned as an example of a series for which you need to know quite a bit about rational approximations to $\pi$ to prove convergence, in a comment to the following MO question. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/54758/does-the-following-series-converge

Comment: @George, thanks for your comment. I would be happy to hear the details if someone here knows them....

Comment: I haven't seen a proof of this, but I *think* the result will follow from equidistribution, showing that the positive and negative terms in the series largely cancel each other. You will probably need to use the fact that $\pi$ has finite irrationality measure to get a good enough bound to prove convergence, as with David Speyer's response to this previous question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2270/convergence-of-sum-n-1-infty-sinnk-n

Comment: If $f$ is a smooth function with period 1 and $\alpha$ has finite irrationality measure, then you can bound $\sum_{n=1}^Nf(\alpha n)-N\int_0^1f(x)dx$. Then, you can bound $\sum_{n=1}^N(-1)^nf(\alpha n)$. I think this could work for this sum by appying equidistribution to the $\cos n$ part, but I haven't been through the details yet.

Comment: There is another series whose convergence depends on subtle details of $\pi$, namely how rarely a sine or cosine is "extreme" when evaluated at integer values, and that is the [Flint Hills series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FlintHillsSeries.html) $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3(\sin n)^2}$$ named for [the toponym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flint_Hills) by [C. A. Pickover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_A._Pickover).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This replaces my original answer, which was faulty but led in the right direction (I think).

I'll let the series start at some $n_0\ge2$; the reason for this will become apparent later.

Expand in $\cos(n)/\ln(n)$ (with $\lvert\cos(n)/\ln(n)\rvert < 1$ for $n \ge 2$):

\[\sum_{n=n_0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\ln(n)} \frac{\cos^k(n)}{\ln^k(n)}\]

Let's interchange the summations and worry later whether that was OK:

\[\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{n=n_0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\ln(n)} \frac{\cos^k(n)}{\ln^k(n)}\]

Now the inner sum converges according to [Dirichlet's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test). In fact we can proceed as in the proof of Dirichlet's test to bound its limit (suppressing indices $k$ while we work at fixed $k$):

\[a_n=\ln^{-k-1}(n)\]
\[b_n=(-1)^n\cos^k(n)=\sum_{j=0}^k\alpha_{jk}\cos((j + \pi)n)\;,\]

with $\lvert\alpha_{jk}\rvert \le 1$, using [the power-reduction formula for the cosine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_identities#Power-reduction_formula) and absorbing the factor $(-1)^n$ into the cosines by adding $\pi$ to their frequency.

\[B_m=\sum_{n=n_0}^m \; b_n\]

\[\lvert B_m\rvert = \left\lvert\sum_{n=n_0}^m \sum_{j=0}^k
\alpha_{jk}\cos((j + \pi)n)\right\rvert
\le \sum_{j=0}^k\left\lvert\sum_{n=n_0}^m\cos((j + \pi)n)\right\rvert \le \sum_{j=0}^k\frac{2}{1 - \cos(j + \pi)}=:M_k\]

\[\left\lvert\sum_{n=n_0}^m a_n b_n\right\rvert = \left\lvert B_m a_{m+1}+\sum_{n=n_0}^{m}B_n(a_n-a_{n+1})\right\rvert\le\]
\[\le M_k a_{m+1} + \sum_{n=n_0}^{m}M_k(a_n-a_{n+1})=
M_k a_{m+1} + M_k(a_{n_0}-a_{m+1}) = M_ka_{n_0}\]

Thus, we can apply the [comparison test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_test) with the following series:

\[\sum_{k=0}^\infty M_k\ln^{-k-1}(n_0)\]

This shows why we need to start at some $n_0$ instead of $2$, which wouldn't work since $\ln 2 < 1$.

Now everything depends on the behaviour of $M_k$. The cosine comes arbitrarily close to $1$; when $j$ comes within $\epsilon$ of an odd multiple of $\pi$, then $1/(1-\cos (j + \pi)) \approx 1/(1-(1 - \epsilon^2/2))= 2/\epsilon^2$. Heuristically speaking, we might expect this to happen every $1/\epsilon$ integers, so on average these spikes would not destroy the long-term decay with $\ln^{-k-1}(n_0)$ (which can be made quantitively, though not qualitatively, stronger by increasing $n_0$). However, I don't know how to make this argument rigorous, or whether that is even possible given the "unpredictability" of $\pi$. It's interesting that this proof might depend on the details of $\pi$ in this way. [Update: Thanks to George Lowther for the comments pointing to [this MathWorld page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html), which gives an upper bound on the irrationality measure of $\pi$ (never heard of that before :-). That this is finite implies that $M_k$ can be bounded by a power of $k$, and hence the outer sum converges (uniformly) -- I believe that completes the proof.]

Assuming that the spike problem can be solved, we still have the interchangeability of the sums to come back to. [This theorem](https://web.archive.org/web/20100817081111/http://math.la.asu.edu/~jss/courses/fall06/mat472/limit_interchange.pdf) shows that we may interchange the sums if the convergence of

\[\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{n=n_0}^m \frac{(-1)^n}{\ln(n)} \frac{\cos^k(n)}{\ln^k(n)}\]

is uniform in $m$ -- which it is, since $m$ dropped out in the derivation of the bound $M_ka_{n_0}$.

To summarize, this derivation shows that the series can be shown to converge if the irregular spikes in $1/(1-\cos (j + \pi))$ that occur because $j$ gets arbitrarily close to odd multiples of $\pi$ can be shown not to destroy the convergence of the outer sum over $k$.

Thanks for an interesting question :-).

Comment: I don't follow how you conclude the last inequality in the line that starts $|B_m|.$ Putting a few random figures into wolframalpha gives $\sum_{n=5}^{100} \cos((1+\pi)n) \approx 0.689574$ but
$1/(1-\cos(1+\pi)) \approx 0.649223,$ which appears to contradict what you've written when $j=1.$

Comment: @Derek Jennings: I'll look into that later tonight; I may have lost a factor of 2 somewhere, but the general idea is to write the cosine as a sum of exponentials and use the formula for the partial sum of a geometric series, so I think the inequality is right except perhaps for a wrong factor. More later...

Comment: @Derek Jennings: You're right, I dropped a factor of 2. Thanks for spotting that. If you reduce the two fractions you get from the geometric series to a common denominator, you get 8 terms of absolute value $1$ in the numerator, and $4(1-\cos(j+\pi))$ in the numerator, so the bound has to be $2 / (1-\cos(j+\pi))$.

Comment: @joriki: +1 Well done. If there are any remaining problems, I cannot see them. The argument seems good to me now. I'm wondering if the problem can be solved without appealing to the irrationality measure of $\pi$ by looking at the differences of the given series and $\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n/ \log n.$ I tried this approach and it seemed promising, at first, but I can't make it rigorous.

Comment: @Derek: No. Consider replasing the $\cos n$ in the denominator by $\cos(2\pi\alpha n)$. Even for irrational $\alpha$ the sum can diverge when it has infinite irrationality measure. Convergence works here because $\alpha=1/2\pi$ has finite irrationality measure.

Comment: @George Lowther: When you say "the sum can diverge", do you mean we can't tell whether it diverges using this kind of proof, or do you mean there actually are values of $\alpha$ for which it diverges? If the latter, how is this proved?

Comment: @joriki: I mean that there actually are values of $\alpha$ for which it diverges. If $\alpha/\pi=p/q$ is rational with odd $p,q$, then it can be seen that $\cos \alpha n$ is periodic and the odd and even terms in the series do not quite balance. So, it diverges. Even irrational $\alpha$ can lead to divergence if $\alpha/\pi$ can be approximated well enough by odd fractions.

Comment: The sum over $k$ comes from expanding $1/(1+x)$, so it should have $(-1)^k$. This does not affect the result of this solution though. Very nice!

Answer (score 0):

Inserting `\sum_{n=2}^{infty} (-1)^n/(ln(n)+cos(n))` into the search box of [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bn=2%7D%5E%7Binfty%7D%20%28-1%29%5En/%28ln%28n%29%20+cos%28n%29%29) gives an approximate value of –4.552162944044021. However unbelievable the actual sum may be, you can be a bit sure about its convergence.

Comment: thanks for the comment, but I was hoping for a proof.