# Prove $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{( - 1)^n}{\ln n + \sin n} $ is convergent.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Help prove the alternating series $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\ln n + \sin n}$ is convergent. $\frac 1 {\ln n + \sin n}$ is a decreasing sequence but it is not motonically decreasing. I am not sure how to deal with this situation.

My failed attempt..

For even terms,

> $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty  \frac{( - 1)^{2n}}{\ln 2n + 1} \le \sum_{n = 1}^\infty  \frac{( - 1)^{2n}}{\ln 2n + \sin 2n} \leqslant \sum_{n = 1}^\infty  \frac{( - 1)^{2n}}{\ln 2n - 1} $$
>
> where the two "bound" series do not converge

For odd terms

> $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{( - 1)^{2n + 1}}{\ln (2n + 1) - 1} \leqslant \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{2n + 1}}{\ln (2n + 1) + \sin (2n + 1)}  \leqslant \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{( - 1)^{2n + 1}}{\ln 2n + 1 + 1} $$
>
> where the two "bound" series do not converge.

Comment: Try using the fact that $-1\leq \sin(n)\leq 1$.

Comment: By itself, those inequalities don't help: the Alternating Series Test has hypotheses that are false for this series.

Comment: The alternating series only requires that $a_n$ is eventually decreasing. A finite amount of terms does not effect convergence.

Comment: The function $\frac1{\ln x+\sin x}$ is not eventually decreasing.

Comment: First time I've seen "{\text{ + }}" in MathJax code where simply "+" was appropriate.

Comment: This is pretty hardcore. I don't think this will be any easier than http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21175/does-the-following-series-converge (which is the same series, only with $\sin(n)$ replaced by $\cos(n)$).

Comment: In the @levap's link, the series with $\cos(n)$ converges. The same method  applies to this one. Thus, this series converges.

Comment: @i707107 The argument there does not show that the series converges. Rather, it reduces the problem to an open question in what is in essence Diophantine approximations.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo In the link, the answer was edited at least once. First version without the knowledge on Diophantine approximations, and second version after the Diophantine approximation result provided by George Lowther.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Also, finiteness of irrationality measure of $\pi$ is not an open question. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html

Comment: @i707107 Ah, yes. Nice. Thanks.

Comment: @i707107 Yes, I first only skimmed the answer and thought that a more precise estimate was needed. Nice problem.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Although finiteness of irrationality measure of $\pi$ is known, but finding an exact value of it is still an open question. Some infinite series such as $\sum 1/(n^3 \sin^2 n)$ depends heavily on the value of it. This series is known as Flint Hills series, and it is not known whether it converges or diverges.

Answer (score 4):

Does
$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\ln n + \sin n}
$
converge or diverge?

I think that it probably diverges,
but I can show that
the similar sum
$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\ln n + (-1)^n}
$
diverges
and
$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\ln n + c}
$
converges
for any real $c$
such that
$\ln(n)+c
\ne 0$
for all $n$
(in particular
for
$c > 0$).

If $f(n)$ is bounded,
let
$s_m
=\sum\limits_{n = 1}^m \frac{(-1)^n}{\ln n + f(n)}
$
and let
$s
=\lim_{m \to \infty} s_m
$
if the limit exists.

$\begin{array}\\
s_{2m}
&=\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{2m} \frac{(-1)^n}{\ln n + f(n)}\\
&=\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{m} (\frac{-1}{\ln (2n-1) + f(2n-1)}+\frac{1}{\ln (2n) + f(2n)})\\
&=\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{m} \frac{-(\ln (2n) + f(2n))+(\ln (2n-1) + f(2n-1))}{(\ln (2n-1) + f(2n-1))(\ln (2n) + f(2n))}\\
&=\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{m} \frac{\ln (1-1/(2n)) + f(2n-1)-f(2n)}{(\ln (2n-1) + f(2n-1))(\ln (2n) + f(2n))}\\
&=\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{m} \frac{\ln (1-1/(2n))}{(\ln (2n-1) + f(2n-1))(\ln (2n) + f(2n))}+\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{2m} \frac{f(2n-1)-f(2n)}{(\ln (2n-1) + f(2n-1))(\ln (2n) + f(2n))}\\
&=u_m+v_m\\
\end{array}
$

where
$u_m
=\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{2m} \frac{\ln (1-1/(2n))}{(\ln (2n-1) + f(2n-1))(\ln (2n) + f(2n))}
$
and
$v_m
=\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{2m} \frac{f(2n-1)-f(2n)}{(\ln (2n-1) + f(2n-1))(\ln (2n) + f(2n))}
$.

Each term in $u_m$
is,
for large enoough $n$,
 less in absolute value than
$\frac1{n\ln^2(n)}
$
(because
$\ln(1-1/(2n))
\approx -\frac1{2n}$
and
$(\ln (2n-1) + f(2n-1))(\ln (2n) + f(2n))
\approx \frac1{\ln^2(n)}
$)
and the sum of these converges.

Therefore convergence
depends on $v_m$.
Each term in $v_m$
is
$ \frac{f(2n-1)-f(2n)}{(\ln (2n-1) + f(2n-1))(\ln (2n) + f(2n))}
\approx  \frac{f(2n-1)-f(2n)}{\ln^2(2n)}
$.

If
$f(n) = c$,
where $c$ is a constant,
then
$f(2n-1)-f(2n) = 0$,
so $v_m = 0$
and the sum converges.

If $f(n) = (-1)^n$,
then
$f(2n-1)-f(2n)
= (-1)-(1)
= -2
$
and the sum of
$\frac{-2}{\ln^2(n)}
$
diverges.

If
$f(n) = \sin(n)$,

$\begin{array}\\
f(2n-1)-f(2n)
&=\sin(2n-1)-\sin(2n)\\
&=2\sin((2n-1-2n)/2)\cos((2n-1+2n)/2)\\
&=2\sin(-1/2)\cos(2n-1/2)\\
\end{array}
$

so the sum depends
on the sum
$\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{\cos(2n-1/2)}{\ln^2(2n)}
$.

According to Wolfy,
$\sum_{n=1}^m \cos(2 n - 1/2) 
= \csc(1) \sin(m) \cos(m + 1/2)
$
so this sum is bounded
but not convergent.
I think that
this implies that
$\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{\cos(2n-1/2)}{\ln^2(2n)}
$
does not converge.
This might be proved
using a variation of
 summation by parts,
but I am not sure
how to do this,
so I will leave it
at this.

Comment: Good job, I was starting to suspect this sum diverges, just because nobody can manage to prove it converges.  But I'd still love to see a complete rigorous proof.

Comment: Your sums after the first one should be to $m$ not to $2m$.  Also how do you get the bound on $u_m$ as less than $\frac1{n\ln^2(n)}$ for large enough $n$?

Comment: Thanks. I made the correction and added an additional explanation.

Comment: The integral
$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{\cos(2t-1/2)}{\ln^2(2t)} \,dt
$$
does converge (use integration by parts, differentiating $\frac1{\ln^2(2t)}$ and integrating $\cos(2t-1/2)$). So I suspect the sum
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(2n-1/2)}{\ln^2(2n)}$$
also converges, and indeed summation by parts is probably how it can be proved.

Comment: What I consider probable is that the sum is bounded but oscillates, so that it does not converge to a limit.

Comment: The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(2n-1/2)}{\ln^2(2n)}$ is convergent by the Dirichlet test since $1/\ln^2(2n) \downarrow 0$ and you already showed the partial sums of $\cos(2n-1/2)$ are bounded.

Comment: @martycohen In wolfram says that the sum converges and it gives also a value of the sum.

Comment: What value? Alpha seems to show the partial sums oscillating from about -.13 to -.15.

Comment: The sum converges. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21175/convergence-of-the-series-sum-limits-n-2-infty-frac-1n-lnn?noredirect=1&lq=1, also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2384464/does-the-series-sum-limits-n-2-infty-1n-ln-left1-frac-sin-n-ln-n-r. The same method applies.