# Does the series of squares of Legendre polynomials converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions

I am a physicist working on an electrostatic problem and this series popped up:
$\sum^{\infty}_{l=0} (P_l(x))^2$
where $P_l$ is the $l$-th Legendre polynomial. Computing this numerically I think the series converges for $x\in(-1,1)$. I don't have the proper knowledge and experience to find out whether it really does. So:
1. Does the series converge?
2. If it does - what is the sum?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials

Comment: Thanks, but I still can't see how to prove it converges. I have a feeling it could be proven with the ratio test, however I don't see the solution. And I have no clue at all about the sum.

Comment: Although it does not converge, I would think there might be an associated distribution for it, like dirac delta or its derivatives... See
http://www-elsa.physik.uni-bonn.de/~dieckman/InfProd/InfProd.html#SeriesxofxLegendrexPolynomials

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question is delicate, but the series does not always converge. A
formula of Laplace ((8.21.2) in Szego's book *Orthogonal Polynomials*)
states that for $0<\theta<\pi$,
$$ P_n(\cos\theta) =
2^{1/2}(n\pi\sin\theta)^{-1/2}\cos((n+\frac12\theta)-\pi/4) +
O(n^{-3/2}).$$
Consequently $\sum |P_n(\cos \theta)|^2$ converges if and only if $$\sum n^{-1}
\cos^2\left((n+\frac12)\theta-\pi/4\right)$$ does. But this series does not
converge for many values of $\theta$ rationally related to $\pi$, for
which there is an arithmetic progression of terms equal to $1/n$. The
answer to
[this
question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109029/convergence-divergence-of-infinite-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac-sinn2)  may be relevant when $\theta$ is not rationally related to
$\pi$.