# Convergence of an infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{n^{2 + \sin n}}$ converge?  Why?

It seems as if this series will converge since $2 + \sin n > 1$ for all integers $n$, but since $2 + \sin n$ is arbitrarily close to $1$ for some $n$ I cannot immediately use a comparison test.

Comment: The series diverges. This is addressed by the same technique as the first of the two series mentioned in my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/109029/462).

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, the series diverges.  An overview of the in-depth approach can be found in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/309788/23353), which links to a paper with a general approach for this type of series.