# Convergence of a series (quite frustrating)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The sum is $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}\left( \frac{\sin{k} + 2}{3}  \right) ^k$$

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Root test (in its stronger limsup form), gives nothing, so I didn't bother with the ratio test. This also rules out any hope of forming bounds and comparing to another (geometric) series.
- Actual numerical investigation, which was totally futile.
- Some other tests that I happen to know, which were inconclusive.

How might this be done?

Comment: The graph of partial sums doesn't look promising when I plug it in to [W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+k+%3D1+to+infty+%281%2F%28k*3^k%29%29%28sin%28k%29+%2B+2%29^k).  The partial sums seem to always increase...

Comment: @anorton I personally wasn't able to find anything at all from the partial sums. It's entirely anecdotal in my opinion at least.

Comment: It is **very** anecdotal/circumstantial, but I'm seeing a pattern (as I zoom out on the graph) that it consistently grows in a logarithmic-ish fashion.  Certainly not proof, but it makes me think that trying to prove divergence might be more promising than proving convergence.  This correlates with Steve Krass' answer below...

Comment: Hmmm, you could be right there. I don't know!

Comment: Well, now I'm beginning to believe the opposite! See my now-longer answer. It's late, and I may have slipped up, but I think we're getting close to an answer, at least!

Comment: This is a duplicate (and an interesting, difficult problem). See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/309788/462).

Comment: Thanks, Andres! The answer there is great. I added the link you provided to my answer, in case anyone overlooks this comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**: This is closer to an answer. (I think the series converges.)

**Update 2**: The series does in fact converge. In a comment to the original question here, Andres Caicedo  mentioned this [earlier identical question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109029/convergence-divergence-of-infinite-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac-sinn2) on MSE, which includes a rigorous answer.

The possibility that this series diverges comes from the fact that $\sin k$ regularly gets very close to one.

Given a small $\epsilon>0$, suppose $\sin k>1-\epsilon$ for at least one value of $k$ in every block of one million integers. Then $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}\left( \frac{\sin{k} + 2}{3}  \right) ^k>
\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1000000m}\left( \frac{3-\epsilon}{3}  \right) ^{1000000m}=-\frac{\log(1-(1-\epsilon)^{1000000})}{1000000}.$$

We can be precise about how often $\sin k>1-\epsilon$ (on average) by finding the function $N(\epsilon)$ for which it’s true that $\sin k>1-\epsilon$ for on average one integer in $N(\epsilon)$.

First, $\sin k = \sin(k \pmod {2\pi})$, and because $\pi$ is irrational, the real numbers $k \pmod {2\pi}$ are uniformly distributed on the interval $[0,2\pi)$. The value of $\sin x$ exceeds $1-\epsilon$ for those $x$ values between $\arcsin(1-\epsilon)$ and $\pi-\arcsin(1-\epsilon)$, which accounts for the fraction $\frac{\arccos(1-\epsilon)}{\pi}$ of the interval.

In other words, the fraction of integers $k$ for which $\sin k>1-\epsilon$ is $\frac{\arccos(1-\epsilon)}{\pi}$ and, on average, $\sin k>1-\epsilon$ for one integer in $\frac{\pi}{\arccos(1-\epsilon)}$.

I assume (but I don’t know the justification) that this asymptotic result is enough to justify the “1 in a million” argument above (at worst with $\alpha N(\epsilon)$ for some $\alpha$ slightly less than $1$). If so,

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}\left( \frac{\sin{k} + 2}{3}  \right) ^k>-\frac{\log(1-(1-\epsilon)^{\frac{\pi}{\arccos(1-\epsilon)}})}{\frac{\pi}{\arccos(1-\epsilon)}}$$

for all $\epsilon>0$.

If

$$-\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\frac{\log(1-(1-\epsilon)^{\frac{\pi}{\arccos(1-\epsilon)}})}{\frac{\pi}{\arccos(1-\epsilon)}}=\infty,$$

the original series diverges.

However, this limit appears to be zero, or so says Mathematica. This can probably be derived using the approximation $\arccos(1-x)\approx \sqrt{2x}$ near $x=0$.

I think the failed approach to show divergence can be turned into a proof of convergence as follows, but I find it worrisome that the actual value of $N(\epsilon)$ doesn’t seem to be important.

From before, we know that for $\epsilon>0$, $\sin k\le1-\epsilon$ for the proportion $1-\frac{1}{N(\epsilon)}$ of integers. Then I think it’s the case that

$\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}\left( \frac{\sin{k} + 2}{3}  \right) ^k&<\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{N(\epsilon)m+1}\left( \frac{3-\epsilon}{3} 
 \right)^{N(\epsilon)m+1}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k}\left(\frac{3-\epsilon}{3}
  \right) ^{k}\\
&=-\frac{\log(1-(1-\epsilon)^{N(\epsilon)})}{N(\epsilon)}+\log 3-\log\epsilon.
\end{align}$

A tight upper limit isn't required, so choose any nonzero $\epsilon$ and assume no more about $N(\epsilon)$ than that it’s a number (even though we know its value) to get an upper bound for the sum. I know this is a bit sloppy, but hopefully it helps and will get streamlined.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution but an idea that might help you out:
$$\sum_{k \geq 1} \cfrac{1}{k}\left( \cfrac{\sin k + 2}{3} \right)^k = \sum_{k \geq 1} \cfrac{1}{3^kk}\left( \sin k + 2 \right)^k=\sum_{k \geq 1} \cfrac{1}{3^kk} \left(\sum_{l = 0}^k {k \choose l}\sin^lk\cdot2^{k-l} \right).$$
Now, $\sin k \leq 1$, so the sum is less than or equal
$$\sum_{k \geq 1} \cfrac{1}{3^kk} \left(\sum_{l = 1}^k {k \choose l}2^{k-l} \right)=\sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{1}{k}\left(\cfrac{2}{3}\right)^k\left( \sum_{l = 0}^k {k \choose l} \cfrac{1}{2^l} \right)= \\
\sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{1}{k}\left(\cfrac{2}{3}\right)^k\left( \sum_{l = 0}^k \cfrac{k!}{l!(k-l)!} \cfrac{1}{2^l} \right) = \sum_{k \geq 1} \left(\cfrac{2}{3}\right)^k\left( \sum_{l = 0}^k \cfrac{(k-1)!}{l!(k-l)!} \cfrac{1}{2^l} \right).$$
If you manage to bound the inner sum (I haven't figured it out, I must confess; but at first glance it seems doable) then you are done.

Comment: Mathematica claims that $\sum_{l = 0}^k \cfrac{(k-1)!}{l!(k-l)!} \cfrac{1}{2^l}=\cfrac{(\frac{3}{2})^k}{k}$, which would unfortunately only show that the sum is less than or equal to $\infty$.

Comment: Yes, bounding $\sin{k}$ by $1$ was quite futile in my investigations as well.

Comment: The inner sum is just $(1 + 1/2)^k$