# $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{(n\log n)^{2-\sin n}}$ diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I know that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^{2-\sin n}}$$ [diverges](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2626391).

But how about $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{(n\log n)^{2-\sin n}}\,?$$

I think it would be very interesting if it converges.

Since ${n\log n}$ and power operation $n^{2-\sin n}$ both are less dense than $n$ itself, on the number line, but still not dense enough to make the sum convergent.

Comment: Hello, the series in the title and in the question are different. Can you clarify which one you are interested in?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. I edited. By the way, I also interested in $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n{(log n)}^{2-\sin(n)}}$
not only $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{(n\log n)}^{2-\sin(n)}}$

Comment: "I know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{n}^{2-\sin(n)}}$ diverges." : Please explain how you know this.

Comment: Sorry for that. By the reference:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2626391/convergence-or-divergence-of-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n2-cos-n

Comment: Please also present your attempts (even if they failed) to adapt that proof to your series. [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391)

Comment: Sorry for that too. I tried several test but I need a little time to organize them and edit.
I will edit it as fast as I can.

Comment: Don't waste your time on the usual tests, which are useless here. Again: please present how you tried to adapt that proof (of divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{n}^{2-\sin(n)}}$)    to your series.