# Convergence of series where $\alpha$ gets close to 1 periodically?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

Its known that $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^\alpha}$$
converges with $\alpha > 1$. But how does something like

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^{2-sin(k)}}$$
behave that gets close to 1 periodically?

The usual tests for convergence failed. Interestlingly I tried this [logarithmic convergence criteria](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmisches_Konvergenzkriterium#:%7E:text=Das%20logarithmische%20Konvergenzkriterium%20ist%20ein,Folge%20positiver%20reeller%20Zahlen%20bilden.) I found on german wikipedia. I states that if the series $$b_k=\frac{ln(k^{sin(k)-1})}{ln(ln(k))}$$ converges to something stricly smaller that $-1$ the series converges. Now i pluged this into [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Limit%5BDivide%5Bln%5C%2840%29k*Power%5Bk%2C-%5C%2840%292-sin%5C%2840%29k%5C%2841%29%5D%5C%2841%29%2Cln%5C%2840%29ln%5C%2840%29k%5C%2841%29%5D%2Ck-%3E%E2%88%9E%5D) and it outputs $-\infty$. But looking at the step-by-step soltion it seems to make a mistake. It applies the product rule for limits wrong IMO.

[image]

Comment: I am pretty sure that something like condition 2 in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/309788/316409) will work to show that the given series is divergent.

Comment: This is not a trivial problem. there is an article [here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82265292.pdf) that give a rather general convergence test for series with positive terms. It is applied to $\sum_n\frac{1}{n^{2+\cos n}}$ and I think the same idea will work for your series. It does involve facts about density of $\sin n$ in $[-1,1]$ and properties of the number $\pi$.

Comment: You may be interested in [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/282259/is-the-series-sum-n-sin-nn-n-convergent) question ("Is the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{|\sin(n)|^n}n$ convergent?").

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2626391/convergence-or-divergence-of-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n2-cos-n?noredirect=1.