# Divergent series $\sum{\frac{1}{n^{2+\cos{n}}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, analysis

Bonjour. 
Show that  $$\sum{\frac{1}{n^{2+\cos{n}}}}$$ is a divergent serie. $$\\$$

My main problem is:
If $\epsilon$ is “infinitely small positive real number” define $A_{\epsilon}$ as the set of all $n, |2+\cos n|\leq 1+\epsilon$ $(n \in A_{\epsilon}\iff-1\leq \cos n \leq -1+\epsilon)$. The divergence should come from the sum over $A_{\epsilon}$ but I have no idea to how to handle this. $$\\$$

Comment: Bonjour. What have you tried?

Comment: Bonjour. I don’t even know where to start. The problem is $2+\cos n$ can be arbitrarily closer to $1$ for infinitely many n. Summing those value we can end with everything.

Comment: If the downvoters can explain why they downvoted, that will be great!

Comment: The downvote button is a toy for some of our friends.

Comment: Physicists are currently working on a universal law that unifies general relativity with quantum mechanics.  Once they are finished they will tackle the more difficult question of why people cast downvote and yet offer no constructive criticism or alternatives.

Comment: Corrected @peterag.

Comment: Do you know that $\sup_{\epsilon > 0} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{1+\epsilon}} = \infty$ ?

Comment: @BerniWaterman Yes but not $\sup_{\epsilon>0} \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{2+\epsilon}}$.

Comment: Divergence of this series has already been addressed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/309788/). You should either delete your question, ask for someone to close it as a duplicate, or ask Andrés E. Caicedo to copy part of his answer here.

Comment: Since you're a French speaker, you can also directly look for the issue 119-1 of the *Revue de la filière mathématique*. There's an entry by Brighi and Chevallier dedicated to the divergence of the series. They give a nice elementary exposition. Here's a [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/aGu7gze.jpg).

Comment: @GabrielRomon I’ve seen that paper using a weak version Denjoy-Koksma inequality, I was just looking for an elementary proof without so sophisticated stuff.