# Prove that $\sum_{k=0}^n{e^{ik^2}} = o(n^\alpha)$, $ \forall \alpha >0$

Tags: real-analysis, summation

I want to prove that : 
$\sum_{k=0}^n{e^{ik^2}} = o(n^\alpha)$, $ \forall \alpha >0$ when $n$ tends to $+\infty$

Perhaps $\sum_{k=0}^n{e^{ik^2}}$ is bounded, I don't know.

Do you have ideas ?

Comment: Section three of [this paper](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/en/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN235181684_0077&DMDID=DMDLOG_0036&LOGID=LOG_0036&PHYSID=PHYS_0338) by [Weyl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Weyl) might be of interest to you (if you can't speak/read German, don't let it scare you, the formulae will tell you everything).

Comment: Weyl differencing is a standard technique here. In general square root cancellation would be the goal, as explained heuristically by the answer below.

Comment: Related (I don't know much about this subject, though): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function#Jacobi_theta_function

Comment: Terry Tao showed that your sum is not bounded. See this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/201250/is-sum-k-1n-sink2-bounded-by-a-constant-m

Comment: Theorem 2.22 of Hardy & Littlewood's paper: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1485887376 shows that your sum is $\Omega(\sqrt n)$. They use transformation formulas of theta functions.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have a proof, but I have a heuristic argument and numerical results that go against your conjecture, which might be interesting to you.

Consider the following heuristic.  For sufficiently large $n$, suppose the terms in the sum will distribute 'randomly' around the unit circle in the complex plane.  In this approximation your summation is equivalent to a random walk in the complex plane with $n$ steps of length 1.  Let
\begin{equation}
f(n) = \sum_{k=0}^n e^{ik^2}.
\end{equation}
Then, the above argument implies not only: 
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Re}(f(n)),\operatorname{Im}(f(n)) \in O(\sqrt{n})
\end{equation}
but even the stronger condition
\begin{equation}
|f(n)|^2 \sim n + g(n)
\end{equation}
with
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Re}(g(n)),\operatorname{Im}(g(n)) \in o(\sqrt{n}).
\end{align}
The correction $g(n)$ comes from the fact that the 'random walk' starts in the positive $\Re$ direction and then heads counter-clockwise in the complex plane, which biases $f(n)$ on the order of the persistence length of the random walk.

So... I checked my idea numerically, and the results are very weird.  Take a look:

[image: $f(n)$ for $n\leq 1000$]
[image: $f(n)$ for $n\leq 10^{10}$]

The orders of magnitude are about right, which supports my heuristic argument.  However, the function is not at all well behaved.  The expected relative fluctuations in $|f(n)|^2$ if it's an $n$-step random walk are $1/\sqrt{n}$; the fluctuations we're seeing here are way larger than this.  Also, there is obviously some periodicity to $|f(n)|^2$, with periods at least as long as $10^9$.  I even suspect there's some self-similarity in $|f(n)|^2$: the entire curve in the second plot isn't so different from the individual little 'teeth', and the function has significant structure both on the scale of $n\sim 10^3$ and $n\sim 10^{10}$.

Personally I highly doubt this function is $o(n^\epsilon)$ $\forall \epsilon>0$, but otherwise I don't know what it is.

Here's the simple code I wrote to generate the above data, if anyone is interested in experimenting:

```
// To compile: gcc -std=c99 -O3 random_walk.c -o random_walk

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define NMAX 1e3
#define PRINT_INTERVAL 1

int main(){
  double sum_real=0.;
  double sum_imaginary=0.;
  for(uint_fast64_t k=0; k<=NMAX; k++){
    double kSquared = (double)k*k;
    sum_real += cos(kSquared);
    sum_imaginary += sin(kSquared);
    if(k%PRINT_INTERVAL==0)
      printf("%e\t%e\n", (double)k, sum_real*sum_real + sum_imaginary*sum_imaginary);
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Check your first summation, there is some $n$ in place of $k$, I think. BTW, the $2$ exponent is pretty irrelevant for your argument, isn't it?

Comment: @leonbloy Yes, that was a typo thanks.  Also, you're right about the 2 exponent not playing an obvious role in my argument,  I was thinking about that a minute ago... You know what though?  The pictures look way weirder with $k$ in place of $k^2$.  Very obvious periodicity, and, shockingly, it looks like $|f(n)|^2 < 5\ \forall n<10^8$, which was the upper limit I checked.  If the heuristic holds any weight, it's because $k^2$ is more effective in "randomizing" $|f(n)|^2$ than $k$ is.

Comment: With $k$ instead of $k^2$ it is a bounded geometric series.

Comment: $f(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} e^{ik} = \frac {1-e^{in}} {1-e^i}$, so $|f(n)|^2 \le \frac 4 {(1-\cos 1)^2 + \sin^2 1} \approx 4.350685$. Good numerical analysis.

Comment: Thank you for this analysis ! You are rigth I think and we should have $f(n) = O(\sqrt{n})$ and $\sqrt{n} = O(f(n))$. To show that $f(n) = O(\sqrt{n})$ we have to show that $n^2$ is uniformly distributed on $[0, 2Pi]$, and that should be true because : $\left.N\left[\text{Sum}\left[N\left[\text{Mod}\left[k^2, 2\text{Pi}\right]\right], \{k, 1, 100000\}\right]\right]\right/100000 = 3.138 $ ~ $\pi$ according to mathematica