# How can we determine the convergence or divergence of $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\sin(\sqrt{k})}{\sqrt{k}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Could any  one   find  if the series:

> $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\sin(\sqrt{k})}{\sqrt{k}}$$

is divergent or convergent? I tried  various techniques, but none  of them worked (absolute convergence, Abel formula, inequalities, …). For example if we use Abel's formula, we don't know anything about $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin(\sqrt{k})$, so we can't conclude.

And now I don't know if this series needs cleverness or some advanced technique.

Comment: I think you can use the M-test https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/proving-that-the-sequence-f-nx-sum-limits-k-1n-frac-sinkxk-is

Comment: the M-test is for sequences of functions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For every $m \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$, we have $\sin \sqrt{k} \geqslant \frac{1}{2}$ when

$$\bigl(2m+\tfrac{1}{6}\bigr)\pi \leqslant \sqrt{k} \leqslant \bigl(2m+\tfrac{5}{6}\bigr)\pi.$$

Therefore

\begin{align}
\sum_{(2m+1/6)^2\pi^2}^{(2m+5/6)^2\pi^2} \frac{\sin \sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{k}} &\geqslant \frac{1}{2} \sum_{(2m+1/6)^2\pi^2}^{(2m+5/6)^2\pi^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \\
&> \sum_{(2m+1/6)^2\pi^2}^{(2m+5/6)^2\pi^2}\bigl(\sqrt{k+1} - \sqrt{k}\bigr) \\
&\approx \frac{2}{3}\pi.
\end{align}

The sequence of partial sums is thus not a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: What about $\sum_{k} \frac{\sin(k^2)}{\sqrt{k}}$ ? It's interesting because the argument of the sine changes fast, as opposed to the original series.

Comment: I don't know. $\sin k^{\alpha}$ is much easier to handle when $\alpha \leqslant 1$. No idea whether the oscillation of the partial sums of $\sum \sin (k^2)$ suffices to get convergence.

Comment: The standard tools for dealing with $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin(n^\alpha)}{n^\beta}$ are Van Der Corput's trick and Weyl's inequality. For instance $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin(n^2)}{n}$ is convergent, but to study the convergence of $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin(n^2)}{\sqrt{n}}$ is more difficult. This old question of mine is related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215528/two-questions-about-weakly-convergent-series-related-to-sinn2-and-weyls-i

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Van der Corput lemma for oscillatory integrals or the lemma for uniform distribution mod $1$ ?

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM: by Van Der Corput's trick I mean the trick for estimating the magnitude of $\sum_{k=1}^{n} e^{ik^2}$ by squaring.