# How do I prove convergence of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \tfrac{\sin k^2}{k}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How do I prove convergence of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \tfrac{\sin k^2}{k}$?

I would prefer avoid using Taylor expansion...

Comment: integral criterion.. the series will be convergent if the integral $ \int_{1}^{\infty}dx \frac{sin(x^{2})}{x} $ is convergent

Comment: @JoseGarcia No. The integral criterion only works for nonnegative, non-increasing integrands.

Comment: I’m pretty sure that Marvis will appear on this thread soon with a proof using [Dirichlet’s Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test), assuming that $ \left( \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin(k^{2}) \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ is a bounded sequence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not easy. The convergence of the more general series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(n^k)}{n},\quad k>0,
$$
is studied in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2270/convergence-of-sum-limits-n-1-infty-sinnk-n/2275#2275).

Comment: anyway.. what if the series does ont converge :) we simply truncate it and that is all, for example the series $ 1/2 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}cos(nx) $ does not converge