# $\alpha <1$, series $n^{-\alpha} \sum _{k=1}^n \sin (k^2)$ is bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Could you help me answer the question, if there exists $\alpha <1$ such that series $n^{-\alpha} \sum _{k=1}^n \sin (k^2)$ is bounded?

Comment: Maybe it may help to know that the integral sinx² is convergent? (integral test) That might help for your question?

Comment: Integral test does not help at all, since the terms are not positive.

Comment: Try [Dirichlet's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test).

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: Can you put it as an answer? I want to see how Dirichlet's test would apply to this problem.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2270/convergence-of-sum-limits-n-1-infty-sinnk-n Related