# How to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin n\cdot\sin n^2}{n}$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The series is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin n\cdot\sin n^2}{n}$$
It seems to use Dirichlet's test, but I cannot prove $\sum\sin n\cdot\sin n^2$ is bounded.
This question may help --
[Convergence of $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin(n^k)/n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2270/convergence-of-sum-limits-n-1-infty-sinnk-n)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Approach 1: Telescoping Sum**
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\sin(k)\sin\left(k^2\right)
&=\frac12\sum_{k=1}^n(\cos(k(k-1))-\cos(k(k+1)))\\
&=\frac{1-\cos(n(n+1))}2\tag1
\end{align}
$$
Thus, the partial sums are bounded by $1$. [Dirichlet's Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) and $(1)$ say that the original series converges.

---

**Approach 2: Summation by Parts**
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(k)\sin\left(k^2\right)}k
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin(k)\sin\left(k^2\right)}k\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac12\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\cos(k(k-1))-\cos(k(k+1))}k\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac12-\frac{\cos(n(n+1))}{2n}-\frac12\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{\cos(k(k+1))}{k(k+1)}\right)\\
&=\frac12-\frac12\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(k(k+1))}{k(k+1)}\tag2
\end{align}
$$
and the last sum converges by comparison to
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k(k+1)}=1\tag3
$$

Comment: Why does this imply the original series converge?

Comment: @ablmf: Since the sum in this answer is bounded, [Dirichlet's Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) says the sum in the question converges.

Comment: Impressive, I could have bet the sum diverges. It doesn't look that different from the harmonic series.

Comment: @EricDuminil: the terms oscillate, sort of like the alternating harmonic series (which converges to $\log(2)$).

Comment: @robjohn: D'oh! I didn't think about that. It makes perfect sense now!

Comment: I really think, @robjohn, that you cash in on your status as a moderator to garner rep for answering some of the poorest questions asked on this site.  Can you even answer a question that isn't a PSQ and/or homework?  I can't even remember, because you answer so many basic homework questions and "Here's the question directly copied, please do my work for me" questions.

Comment: If you feel that my above assessment is wrong, then *show me otherwise, please!*